# Series equivalent to harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Question**: In the accepted answer, In this link given here
[Another simple series convergence question: $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty \frac1{n (\ln n)\ln(\ln n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280257/168676)

What is mean by last line "**which is essentially the harmonic series"**?

Is that mean, $n\ln^2 2 + \ln2\cdot\ln\ln 2 ≤n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence for their reciprocals, reverse inequality will holds and hence by comparison test, as harmonic series diverges, so that series $\sum\frac {1}{n\ln^2 2 + \ln2\cdot\ln\ln 2}$ diverges ?

Am i correct? Please help..

Comment: They're using the fact that$$\sum\frac1{an+b}$$ is divergent in comparison with some multiple of the Harmonic series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means
$$\frac{1}{n\ln^22+\ln2⋅\ln\ln2} \sim \frac{1}{n\ln^22},$$
and by summing $\frac{1}{n\ln^22}$ you find the harmonic series up to a factor.

More generally, if we have two sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ whose elements are positive real numbers, then we say that these sequences are asymptotically equivalent if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1,$$
and we write $a_n\sim b_n.$

One can verify that $\sum_n a_n$ converge iff $\sum_n b_n$ coverges (hint : $\frac{1}{2}a_n \leq b_n \leq 2a_n$ for $n$ big enough).

Comment: Sir thank you i got it. Can you just elaborate "by summing $\frac{1}{n\ln^2 2}$ you find harmonic series up to a factor" what does it mean?

Comment: Have a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cauchy's condensation test, take n= 2ⁿ, then ∑2ⁿf(2ⁿ) becomes ∑( 1/(ln2)) (1/n ln(n ln2)), for this series also take ,n=2ⁿ, ∑( 1/(ln2)) (1/n ln(n ln2)) becomes ∑( 1/(ln2)) (1/(ln(ln2) + n ln(2)), and clearly this is a divergent series, so the actual series ∑f(n) becomes divergent ( by using two times Cauchy condensation test).

Comment: I want to say "Clearly" is not proof. Can you please elaborate how last series is divergent?

Comment: By comparison test , you can say that the last series is divergent, just take uₙ, as the" nth term of the last series", and vₙ= 1/n.